# Can code that has been given under the WTFPL license and then changed to GPL be changed to anything again after that?

Tags: wtfpl

I gave a friend of mine a piece of code that I wrote that I put under the WTFPL license. This was only available in private, between him and me.

He took it and published it and changed the license to GPL (which is fine for me), but also mentioned me and mentioned that I gave it to him under WTFPL and that he has not done any changes.

Can somebody now come and publish it under a different license? I never publically released it as WTFPL, even though it is publically known to have been released under that license in private. But every derivative has to come from his GPL licensed repository, which is the only one publically available. But still, there it's publically written that I originally wrote it under WTFPL.

Comment: I feel you are missing the point of the WTFPL if you're asking questions about what people do with code which is made available under that license in any form.

Comment: @Philip The question here is *who is* the WTFPL grant made available to, not what recipients may do once they are recipients, i.e., whether people who never got an explicit WTFPL license grant may make use of it under that license. If Alice gave code to Bob under WTFPL in a one-on-one private transfer, can Alice successfully sue Charles for using the code under WTFPL when neither Bob nor Alice ever offered *him* the code under that license?

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Yes, exactly as apsillers says.

Comment: Could they not just modify the work under the GPL license. Since the original license says do whatever you want.

Comment: @Devon Yes, further recipients absolutely could rely on the GPL license grant to make modifications (and perform required source disclosure). The question asked here is whether downstream recipients can use the original author's WTFPL grant that was only offered directly to one person who never explicitly passed it on.

Comment: @apsillers my guess is no as it was not distributed and the op retains copyrightof that version, but functionally it doesn't matter unless the new user wants something less restrictive the GPLv3

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants to take your friends work that includes your work that is licensed under the GPL then they would have to publish under GPL or GPL compatible license.
However, given that no one has distributed the original copy with original license beyond the op and their friend. It seems that other users by default would only be able to work from the GPL version as that is the only one they have access  to and thus subject to its license and not the WTFPL.